# gd warning: product of memory allocation multiplication would exceed INT_MAX

Tags: php, integer, gd

I have this code:

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX . '<br/>';
echo 174400 * 249600 . '<br/>';
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(174400, 249600);
```

and it gives me this output:

```
9223372036854775807
43530240000
Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): gd warning: product of memory allocation multiplication would exceed INT_MAX, failing operation gracefully in /home/bartek/Documents/WWW/WOF/application/controllers/EditorController.php on line 53
```

The first question is why imagecreatetruecolor is failing gracefully? And the second question is what can I do about it? How can I create big images in PHP?

Comment: In a true colour picture, 1 pixel uses a minimum of 3 bytes, so 43530240000 pixels would require 121,62 GB. How much RAM does your server have?

Comment: 121 GB is way too much, I have only 8GB of RAM. But I want to create PNG image and it should not use so much RAM with this resolution.

Comment: If your PNG has alpha channel it'll use 4 bytes per pixel (i.e., 162.16 GB). You must understand that programs work on raw images bytes—compressed image formats are only useful for storage and transmission. I doubt that PHP can manipulate such images—you'll probably have to find a third-party program that doesn't load the full image into memory and call it from your PHP script.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the use case for 40,000 MPx pictures? Are you processing images from a telescope?

Comment: It is map for my game. I'm trying to create map generator.

Comment: I can open PNG of this size in Gimp. Maybe I could generate small images and then join them (all programmatically)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is triggered by guard code in the GD library, which checks for integer overflow. 174400 x 249600 = 43530240000 = 0x0000000A-229AC000. The number does not fit into a 32-bit integer so GD blows up. In theory, someone could go in there and fix the code so 64-bit integers are used instead. No one has done so yet, since it's rather unlikely people will allow more than 4 gig of memory per request. Someday it'll happen.

Incidentally, it takes 5 bytes to store each pixel in GD: one byte for R, G, B, and A, plus one byte for anti-aliasing.

Comment: So whats the solution ?

Comment: There is no solution. An image that large won't open on the client side anyway. There is no point in creating it.

Comment: I have same problem. I am trying to create an equivalent of this script
https://github.com/Fedik/php-maptiler
but using GD instead of ImageMagick, the base image is 50,000px square and needs to be opened to cut into 256px square tiles, this needs to be done every 15 minutes on the server as the base image is updated over time. I guess I have to move server to one in which ImageMagick is installed.